# C++ program has weird output

Tags: c++

```
        // This program defines a person class which includes an
        // overloaded insertion operator.
        // Also included is a personDisplay manipulator
        // that displays a message and sets a field size
        // for the name

    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    #include<iomanip>
        using namespace std;
    class Person
    {
    private:
        int idNum;
        string name;
    public:
        Person(const int, const string);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Person&);
    };
    Person::Person(int id, string nm)
    {
        idNum = id;
        name = nm;
    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Person& p)
    {
        out << p.name << " " << p.idNum << endl;
        return out;
    }
    ostream& personDisplay(ostream& out, Person& p)
    {

        out << "Here is a person: ";
        out.setf(ios::left);
        out.width(12);
        return out;
    }
    int main()
    {
        Person someBody(365, "Gabby");
        cout << personDisplay << someBody << endl;
        int dog;
        cin >> dog;
        return 0;
    }
```

This program is supposed to output "Here is a person:...". instead it outputs "﻿﻿﻿002A11DI...". It does output "Gabby 365". Please help me find the source of the error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `cout << personDisplay` prints the address of the function; that's what you are seeing. If you meant it to be used as a manipulator, drop `Person& p` parameter (you aren't using it anyway).

Comment: You want `cout << someBody << endl;` instead of `cout << personDisplay << someBody << endl;`. The second code prints the address of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Uhh I do not know where to start in here. First of all `personDisplay` is not operator overload. To call this function you should use:

```
personDisplay(std::cout, someBody);
```

Second:

```
std::cout << personDisplay () << ...
```

Since `personDisplay()` returns reference (address) where `out` is located at it will print "garbage". (as  Igor Tandetnik suggested in comments)

Third and only options you can do is:

```
int main()                                                                                                                                    
{   
    Person someBody(365, "Gabby");
    personDisplay(std::cout, someBody) 
    cout << someBody << endl;
    int dog;
    cin >> dog;
    return 0;
}
```